# strange behavior: pcolormesh and meshgrid (easy)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have some data phi, and I want to plot it with pcolormesh.
My first approach was:

```
plt.figure()
plt.colormesh(phi)
plt.show()
```

which produces:

[image: Without Cut]

Good. Now I just want to adjust the axis a little bit, therefore I
use meshgrid:

```
plt.figure()
kk = np.arange(0,phi.shape[1])
gg = np.arange(-phi.shaoe[0]//2 +1 , phi.shape[0]//2 +1,1)
GG, KK = np.meshgrid(gg,kk)
plt.pcolormesh(KK,GG,phi.T)
plt.show()
```

and now I get the following:

[image: with cut]

As you can clearly see, the stripe on the top is cut!! I **cannot** explain this behavior, since I changed nothing on the phi function! I just added the axis data with the grid! What kind of bug is this and how can I solve it!

PS: if you want to reproduce the bug, just use a matrix which is symmetric towards some axis parallel to the y-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document of `pcolor`:  http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor

> Ideally the dimensions of X and Y should be one greater than those of
>   C; if the dimensions are the same, then the last row and column of C
>   will be ignored.

so you need to create two array with one more row and one more column:

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

phi = np.zeros((20, 30))
phi[0, :] = 1
phi[-1, :] = 2

kk = np.arange(0,phi.shape[1]+1)
gg = np.arange(-phi.shape[0]//2 +1 , phi.shape[0]//2 + 2)
GG, KK = np.meshgrid(gg,kk)
pl.pcolormesh(KK,GG,phi.T)
```

Comment: Thank you, I must overseen this in the documentary!